# What is the USE_BIOMETRIC permission needed for?

Tags: android, androidx, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#USE_BIOMETRIC) for the `USE_BIOMETRIC` permission says

> Allows an app to use device supported biometric modalities.

But AndroidX's `BiometricPrompt` **works without** this permission. So what exactly is it needed for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Works because the library already declares it in its own manifest:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/63add6e2590077c18556dcdd96aa5c6ff68eb13b/biometric/biometric/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml